# Moving to a word in bash in Emacs mode

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs

I am using the command line in Emacs mode and would like to move my cursor to a character forwards or backwards. Are there any shortcut keys that I can type to get to that position fast. For e.g., the long command line is

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

and my cursor is at the first character and want to move to the word `over`. Right now I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to bring up the editor and search and save. Any way to do this in Emacs on the command line itself without shifting to vi?

Answer (score 0):

From the bash manual, [on readline commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands):

> `character-search (C-])`
>   A character is read and point is moved to the next occurrence of that
>   character. A negative count searches for previous occurrences.

So, if I had:

```
$ set -o emacs
  ^
```

Then `C-]o` will take me to `o` in `-o`. [You can use counts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Arguments.html#Readline-Arguments) for the search as well, so `M-2 C-] e` will take me to `emacs`.